# Unit Tests for Swift & Objective C files

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I’m having trouble setting up Unit tests (XCTestCase) for my Xcode Project. 
The project contains Objective C and Swift files. 
'Enable testability' and 'Defines Module' is set to 'YES'

I imported the main project with: @testable import Projectname 
I created a separate (empty) Bridging header . And made sure that all te frameworks are imported in the Unit testing Target (through Project > Build Phases).

This works fine for all the Objective C classes/files. But not with the swift classes with have Objective C functions in it.
When i’m running the test it fails. And almost all the #import lines in the main bridging header get the same warning:  `“Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)”`

I also get a warning for the class i try to import:

```
“Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  “Project.BaseController.__allocating_init () -> Project.BaseController", referenced from:
      Main_App.ProjectTests.setUp () -> () in ProjectTests.o
  "type metadata accessor for Flitsmeister.BaseController", referenced from:
      Main_App.ProjectTests.setUp () -> () in ProjectTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)”
```

Is it possible to test Swift files with imported Objective C code? 
Are there workarounds?